# Regex to select all flags, but not attributes (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I have an input string as such:

```
var str = "[header fullwidth short color =red    text = big] [anotherObj flag attr=1] ..."
```

*(**Note:** the spaces are deliberate)*

I want to retrieve the list of objects, with each having three qualities:

- Type of obj: *header*
- List of flags: *["fullwidth", "short", ...]*
- List of attributes: *{color:"red", text:"big", ...}*

I have written this function, which gets the type of object and the attributes, but not the flags (being attributes without values; IE booleans)

```
function parseElements(str) {
  var eles = str.match(/[^\[\]]+(?=\])/g);
  return (eles||[]).filter(function(ele) {
    var split = /\s*([^\s]+)\s*(.*)/.exec(ele);
        type = split[1],
        options = split[2].match(/\s*([a-zA-Z]+\s*=\s*[^\s]+)/gm),
     // flags = NEED REGEX HERE

    return {type: type, options: options, flags: null};
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've come up with?

Comment: Sure ill just edit now

Comment: This seems similar to an HTML start tag without the `<` and `>`.

Comment: Yes it is, but for UX reasons I am choosing to implement a "Short code" style syntax. It is because people familiar with wordpress (ie: my target market) will be used to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the flags try something like this:

```
/ (\w+)(?= [^=])/
```

and then remove the `header` (as in take all matches but the first) as this seems easiest.

A quick expalanation: this will match 1 or more word characters preceded by 1 or 2 non equals characters (which are in `[a-zA-Z_]`) as long as they are not followed by 2 non-equals signs which all your attributes are.

EDIT: I wrote this before your post, so it matches on the entire string, before you split it.

EDIT 2: With discussion on chat (see below) I realised that optional spaces are allowed on both sides, this doesn't work in javascript due to the lack of a negative lookbehind operator, the requirement for optional spaces on both sides was dropped and the regex above works. Thanks to Sharang for confirming that this is the case (If anyone can think of a way that this is possible with optional spaces on both sides with a single regex I'd be very interested to see it, I think it's impossible, as stated)

EDIT 3: it was pointed out that attributes are optional so the new regex needed is:

```
/ (\w+)(?=(?: [^=])|$)/gm
```

basically the same but allowing it to be followed by the end of the line.

Comment: Even so, with input of:
    [header fullwidth short color =red    text = big] 
You get ouput of
    ["header", "fullwidth", "short", "colo", "red", "tex", "big"]

Comment: Cheers. Note, it can have spaces between the "=".

Comment: hmm... I'm unsure about it because of the optional space between the = and it's value which doesn't help. Just to double check, is there a required space between the key and it's value in the attributes?

Comment: No, the spaces are optional. Its the same as html.
Eg, all of these are valid:
[header flag atr=1]
[header flag atr = 1]
[  header flag atr=1  ]

Comment: fixed it to work with optional spaces on both sides.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50751/discussion-between-mike-h-r-and-tristan-matthias)

Comment: Hey Mike, I just discovered a bug with this. Details in chat.